# Connectedness and path connectedness, of irreducible affine algebraic set in $\mathbb C^n$, under usual Euclidean topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $n\ge 2$ and $V$ be an irreducible affine algebraic set in $\mathbb C^n$ . Then is it true that $V$ is path connected (or at least connected ) in the usual Euclidean topology of $\mathbb C^n$  ?

Comment: This is true even for $n=1$.

Comment: @Mohan: true ... for $n=1$, any irreducible affine algebraic set in $\mathbb C$ is singleton ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, $V$ is connected. The relevant theorem is the following:

**Connectedness theorem.

Let $X$ be an irreducible complex projective variety. If $Y \subsetneq X$ is a  Zariski-closed strict subset, then $X\setminus Y$ is connected in the classical topology.**

Now, if $X=\bar V\subset \mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)$ and $Y=X\cap  H$ (where $H=\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)\setminus \mathbb C^n$=hyperplane at infinity), we have $V=X\setminus Y$ and the theorem applies, proving the connectedness of $V$.

*Reference for connectedness theorem:* [Mumford, Algebraic Geometry I](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9783540586579), (4.16) page 68.

**Edit: direct proof of path connectedness**
Let $p:\tilde V\to V$ be a [desingularization](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970486?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of $V$.
For $a,b\in V$ there exist $\tilde a, \tilde b\in \tilde V$ with $p(\tilde a)=a, p(\tilde a)=b$.
Join $\tilde a, \tilde b\in \tilde V$ by a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to \tilde V$ (possible since $\tilde V$ is a connected complex manifold).
The path $p\circ \gamma$ then joins $a$ to $b$, qed.

**Note to killjoys :-)**
Grumpy people who wish to point out that my proof might not be completely elementary should show Hironaka some respect : he didn't work years on desingularization in order to have spoilsports prohibiting mention of his work!

Comment: What about path connected ?

Comment: Path-connectedness is true too: see my edit.

Comment: Why is $\tilde V$ a connected (in Euclidean topology ?) complex manifold ? Is $p$ continuous in Euclidean topology ? It would be good if you could please give some references ....

Comment: A complex manifold is in particular a real differentiable manifold, hence it is path-conneced iff it is connected. See [Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd Ed.](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-John-Lee-ebook/dp/B00DGEQEVQ) Prop. A43, page 608.

Comment: I was having the doubt about why is it connected ... is it because it is an irreducible variety ? And why is $p$ continuous in the Euclidean topology ?

Comment: a) Yes, because of irreducibility. b) The map $p$ being algebraic induces a holomorphic map between the underlying complex varieties and *a fortiori* that map is continuous.[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry) is a reference for these GAGA-type results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you also please take a look at these questions  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629855/is-the-complement-of-a-complex-affine-algebraic-set-in-an-irreducible-complex-af                           https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629897/does-an-irreducible-real-affine-algebraic-set-its-complement-has-finitely-many

Comment: Could you recommend a reference for your proof of path-connectedness? Thank you!

Comment: @12345 As a first approximation [Wikipedia' article on desingularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities) is, as usual, excellent. For a semi-technical account with actual calculations [the report by Hauser](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-03/S0273-0979-03-00982-0/S0273-0979-03-00982-0.pdf) is a user-friendly account of Hironaka's result, enriched by beautiful pictures.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thanks a lot! Is it possible to extend your proof of path-connectedness to the setting of connectedness theorem in Mumford, i.e., when $V=X \backslash Y$ for some varieties X and Y and V is not a variety itself? If not, are there alternative approaches? Is your approach equivalent to the one stated here https://mathoverflow.net/a/62883 ? Thank you!