# Is the complement of a complex affine algebraic set in an irreducible complex affine algebraic set (path) connected in the euclidean topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry, several-complex-variables, affine-varieties

Let $n \ge 2$, and $V$ be an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb C^n$ and $W$ be an irreducible affine algebraic set in $\mathbb C^n$, with $V \subsetneq W$ ; then is it true that $W \setminus V$ is connected in the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb C^n $ ? Is it path connected in the Euclidean topology ?

I can see that $W \setminus V$ is connected in the Zariski topology of $\mathbb C^n$, but I can't figure out in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: Sean Lawton's answer here answers your question, but ends up referencing a book of Mumford: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62843/path-connectedness-of-varieties. I think you can also use roy smith's answer, and the fact that $\mathbb C$ minus a finite number of points is path-connected, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Dap : But $W \setminus V$ is not an algebraic set I think ...

Comment: You can adapt my [answer to your preceding question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2628615/3217) to see that $W\setminus V$ is connected in the classical  topology. The key point is that, denoting by a bar the closure in $ \mathbb P^n$ of a subset of $\mathbb C^n$ , we have $\bar W \setminus \bar V=W  \setminus V$. We can then use the result I called the **Connectedness theorem** in my preceding answer.